# How to determine if a colour is black or grey?

Tags: colors

I am importing text, and I have to be able to tell if the text is either grey or black vs some other colour.

Is there a way to determine if a given colour is black or grey? I looked at Relative Luminance but I'm not sure that tells me that it's black or grey. I'm spending a lot of time fiddling with HSV/HSL but I seem to always be able to find exceptions.

Currently I have

```
bool isGreyOrBlack = (c.saturationF() < 0.13 && c.valueF() < 0.40) || (c.saturationF() >= 0.13 && c.lightnessF() < 0.10);
```

But it doesn't work very well.

Comment: Language you are using? and maybe a better example of how you are trying to do this? Let me expand a bit - can you give us a complete function so we have a better idea what you want?  TIA!

Comment: I am using C++ with QT (where c is a QColor), but language shouldn't make any difference - it seems like there should be an algorithm/calculation to use HSL / HSV to be able to tell when a colour is grey or black...